# Getting error trying to start process

Tags: c#, process

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("SnippingTool"))
{
    process.Kill();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    process.Start();
}
```

I'm trying to restart a .exe using Process. Why isn't this working? Thought it should be able to find the process since it success killing it.

Getting this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start process because a file
>   name has not been provided

EDIT: To clarify, the `process.Kill` works, it's the `Start()` that gets exception.

Comment: I think it comes down to the fact that the way you are getting the process means that the executable path is never required (since it is already running), thus the file name parameter is never set

Comment: Check whether FilName and WorkDirectory property are set correctly or not before Process.Start get executed.

Comment: process.Kill() needs ProcessId. It doesn't require process physical location. And GetProcessesByName doesn't rpovide process location. So that process.Start() cannot restart the process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you aren't getting the file location of the process, and it doesn't know how to start it. Doing the following will work, however if you are running a 64-bit machine, you should make sure that you compile your program in 64-bit (Project Properties -> Build -> Platform Target: x64)[image]

```
foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessByName("SnippingTool"))
{
    string fullPath = process.MainModule.FileName;
    process.Kill();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Process.Start(fullPath);
}
```

I've tested this and it worked for me

Comment: Hmm...Can't access it because of System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process

Comment: @krillezzz You'll need to change the properties of your project to target x64 platforms

Comment: Can't find that option. Using VS 2012. In project properties -> I can only find Target framework (not platform target). Under Configuration manager for Build I can find Active solution platform (set to "Mixed platforms")

Comment: I'm using VS 2012 aswell. In Project properties, there are a bunch of tabs at the side, one of them is 'Build', click that. Then, you should see a 'General' heading, which will have a few checkboxes, a textbox, and a combobox. The combobox should have 3 options: 'Any CPU', 'x86', and 'x64'. Click on 'x64' and save.

Comment: x64 wasn't an option. Right now it's just set as Active platform

Comment: Hang on, let me upload a screen shot

Comment: Okay, check the image I uploaded

Comment: That's strange. How are you getting to your properties window? I'm pressing 'Alt + F7'

Comment: Maybe they have fixed something on my company so I can't change this

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when trying to launch Visual Studio from within Unity.  I needed to reboot my computer to finish the Visual Studio installation first.